# btm_sec_disconnected : Device is NULL

Tags: android, bluetooth

1. Trying to build connection between Nexus4 and Nexus 5 via Insecure Bluetooth Connection. Insecure meaning no pairing is required.
2. The code hence developed did work for sometime and both phones were able to talk to each other. An app on nexus4 would launch via broadcast message when Nexus 5 initiates BL Connection.
3. At some point, i get this

> ```
> E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: aclStateChangeCallback: Device is NULL
> E/bt-btm  btm_sec_disconnected - Clearing Pending flag
> ```

in Nexus4 phone. Post which, I am not getting any Broadcast message when the other phone(Nexus 5) tries to set up a connection. Any pointers why I am getting this ?

PS : Same is working fine across other phones. I did restart Nexus4, renamed bluetooth name. But dint had the luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try restarting the bluetooth or the entire device. I have noticed this issue on devices with the (a particular one?) Broadcom bluetooth chipset. The Android bluetooth stack just decides to close the connection sometimes before it reaches your app. Sometimes I can detect this by listening for ACL_CONNECTED events, I am hoping to programmatically restart the bluetooth by detecting it this way. It goes away most of the time after the restart.

Comment: Thanks Caja, yes, restarting(phone not bluetooth) does work 1 out of 5 times.but my use case is not served there. I am having a broadcast for ACL_CONNECTED/DICONNECTED states and when the error happens, the broadcast receiver never gets any call.